# Can Dialogflow response time limit be modified?

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am making a bot on dialogflow with a webhook. I get an error : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. My webhook takes a bit over 5 seconds to return a response. Is there a way to allow a longer time than 5 seconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. One possibility is to (if you have for example a background task which takes some time) is to send back (before the 5 sec timeout) an Event. This triggers again a call to the Webhook, so you get another 5 sec to finish your background process.

Comment: Won't this make my webhook process start over if it is triggered a second time ?

Comment: It depends on your code.

After the first request you start a background task, with your second request (after the event) you just need to check the status of the background thread (isCompleted flag) and obtain the result.

Comment: @BeppeC Could you elaborate on it by giving a sample code