# Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED | Request timed out

Tags: asp.net, timeout, dialogflow-es

I'm using ASP.Net for back-end webhook. Some of requests are executed successfully and few are receiving this error:

> Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

But when I added a slightly big operation which takes least 2 seconds to complete and responds in around 3 seconds I'm continuously receiving this error.

The issue I think is only request time out. I can't speed up my response as it routes between 2-3 3rd party servers. So in someway I need to increase the response wait time in dialog flow for my bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i received from Dialogflow support.

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to Dialogflow Support. Webhook timeout limit
>   for Actions on Google integration is 10 seconds. For all other
>   integrations, including self-developed implementations sending
>   requests to our API, webhook timeout is 5 seconds. These values are
>   not customizable. The timeout limit includes time for Dialogflow
>   requests to your webhook endpoint, the webhook processing time, and
>   webhook response time back to Dialogflow.
>
> Conversational interfaces are meant to be designed as a continuous
>   message exchange between the end user and the app/bot. If your web
>   service requires more time for executing operations in the background
>   and this cannot be optimized, consider redesigning the conversation
>   flow in such way that end users don't wait for the app/bot reply for
>   more than 5 seconds (10 for Actions on Google).
>
> Let me know if you have any questions.
>
> Regards, Mark Dialogflow Support Team

So the only option is to keep user in conversation while you receive the response from webhook

Comment: Hi @habiba, how can I handle the timeout, so it gives the user a response when time out happen, because it confuse the user if he send a text on chatbot, but didn't get any response, I just want to reply by "time out, please retype, your question"

Comment: @usamasulaiman in dialogflow there is no option in dialogflow to override this behavior, may in near future they introduce it. if you are just learning i would recommend use IBM Watson conversation, that's more flexible and developer friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not possible I am afraid, you can work around implementing an asynch background thread

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625057/9095551